# Exit out of while loop after method iterates through file of strings and finds matched input answer

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner, user-input

I'm creating a login page for a class assignment and having trouble exiting out of a while loop after a method takes in the username and password then searches through a multi-line text file for a match. It can find a match but goes back to the input area in the main method and asked for the username again. Hope this makes sense.

Any help would be extremely appreciated. As you can tell, I'm new to Java since this code is all over the place and probably a ton of mistakes. I've been up all night trying to figure this out but with no luck. Thanks!

```
package course.registration;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Welcome {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Course Registration System" + "\n");
    System.out.print("Please type Login or Register: ");
    String choice = input.nextLine();

    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Login")){
        System.out.print("Please enter email address to log in: ");
        String email = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter password: ");
        String password = input.nextLine();

        //goes to method to search and match inputs
        VerifyLogin verify = new VerifyLogin();
        verify.VerifyInfo(email, password);
        }

    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Register")) {
        System.out.println("Going to registration Page...");
        }
    input.close();
    }
}
```

Here is the method that searches the text file and tries to find a match for the inputs. I feel like the problem is when the method exits and goes back to the while loop in the main method. I can't figure out a way to exit out of the while loop. Here is how the strings look in the "students_logins.txt" file:

```
jthomas@gmail.com,1234
kwatson@time.com,3333
legal@prog.com,d567
lavern@shirley.com,34
kwatson@gmail.com,12200
```

---

```
package course.registration;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VerifyLogin {
    private String tempUsername;
    private String tempPassword;

    public void VerifyInfo(String email, String password) throws FileNotFoundException {
        boolean login = false;
        File file = new File("student_logins.txt");
        Scanner info = new Scanner(file);
        info.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

        while (info.hasNextLine()) {
            tempUsername = info.next();
            tempPassword = info.next();

            if (tempUsername.trim().equals(email.trim()) && (tempPassword.trim().equals(password.trim()))) {
                System.out.println("Email Address or Password Works!!");
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!login) {
            System.out.println("Email Address or Password is Invalid.");
        }
        info.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move condition insede `while` loop, and if selected condition is final, e.g. user has enterd valid login and password, then use `break` to exit the loop. Otherwise, loop will be continued:

```
public class Welcome {

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        final LoginValidator loginValidator = new LoginValidator(Welcome.class.getResourceAsStream("student_logins.txt"));

        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Course Registration System");

            int choice = 0;

            while (choice >= 0) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("1: LoginPlease");
                System.out.println("2: Register");
                System.out.print("Your choice: ");

                choice = scan.nextInt();
                scan.nextLine();

                if (choice == 1) {
                    System.out.print("Please enter email address to log in: ");
                    String email = scan.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Please enter password: ");
                    String password = scan.nextLine();

                    if (loginValidator.isValid(email, password)) {
                        System.out.println("Email Address or Password Works!!");
                        break;
                    } else
                        System.out.println("Email Address or Password is Invalid.");
                } else if (choice == 2) {
                    System.out.println("Going to registration Page...");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For *Validation*, it is better to load all logins from file at the application start, and then use it just check `Map`:

```
final class LoginValidator {

    private final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    public LoginValidator(InputStream in) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(in)) {
            scan.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                map.put(scan.next(), scan.next());
                scan.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isValid(String email, String password) {
        return map.containsKey(email) && map.get(email).equals(password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks oleg.cherednik! I was able to figure it out using the code. I needed the boolean method at the bottom of the LoginValidator class.

Answer (score 0):

In the main method you are always staying in the while loop, because you're never obtaining input again.

Before while loop you have:

```
String choice = input.nextLine();
```

So when you provide *Login* as an input while condition is always *true* , so you are staying in this while loop.

If you want to ask user for correct input *Login/Register* till he/she provides it, you can try to use my version of *Welcome* class:

```
public class Welcome {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Course Registration System" + "\n");
    System.out.print("Please type Login or Register: ");
    String choice = input.nextLine();

    while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Login") && !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Register")) {
        choice = input.nextLine();
    }

    if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Login")){
        System.out.print("Please enter email address to log in: ");
        String email = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter password: ");
        String password = input.nextLine();

        //goes to method to search and match inputs
        VerifyLogin verify = new VerifyLogin();
        verify.VerifyInfo(email, password);
    }

    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Register")) {
        System.out.println("Going to registration Page...");
    }
    input.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Przemek! I'm getting close as it's checking if the logins are valid or invalid but if it's invalid it's not prompting to go back to enter the email again. If it's invalid, it continues to the second if statement in the main menu to "Register".  I know we're close!